# Parse Twitter text using PHP preg_replace

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I have the following code which parses the Twitter text to change links, mentions and hashes into hyperlinks:

```
function parseTwitterText($text) {

    $returnText = $text;
    $hashPattern = '/\#([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/i';
    $mentionPattern = '/\@([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/i';
    $urlPattern = '/(http[s]?\:\/\/[^\s]+)/i';
    $robotsFollow = false;

    // SCAN FOR LINKS FIRST!!! Otherwise it will replace the hashes and mentions
    $returnText = preg_replace($urlPattern, '\<a href\="$1" ' + (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel\=\"nofollow\"') + '\>$1\<\/a\>', $returnText);
    $returnText = preg_replace($hashPattern, '\<a href\="http\:\/\/twitter\.com\/\#\!\/search\?q\=\%23$1" ' + (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel\=\"nofollow\"') + '\>\#$1\<\/a\>', $returnText);
    $returnText = preg_replace($mentionPattern, '\<a href\="http\:\/\/twitter\.com\/$1" ' + (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel\=\"nofollow\"') + '\>@$1\<\/a\>', $returnText);
    return $returnText;
}
```

However I'm just getting `0` returned if I had a tweet like `#test`

I based this code on a JavaScript version I had, so wondering if I've done something wrong in the `preg_replace()` that only worked in the JS `replace()`

Comment: To condense strings in PHP you use `.` and not `+` as you would in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. In PHP, you concatenate strings with `.`, not with a `+`. When using `+`, PHP is casting the strings to an integer before adding them, which results in the `0`.
2. In the `preg_replace()` calls, you do not have to escape all the characters in the second parameter. So remove all backslashes within these three lines.

You should end up with something like this:

```
$returnText = preg_replace($urlPattern, '<a href="$1" ' . (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel="nofollow"') . '>$1</a>', $returnText);
$returnText = preg_replace($hashPattern, '<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23$1" ' . (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel="nofollow"') . '>#$1</a>', $returnText);
$returnText = preg_replace($mentionPattern, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" ' . (($robotsFollow)? '':'rel="nofollow"') . '>@$1</a>', $returnText);
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I was just being sloppy and didn't change everything over correctly. Thanks :)

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.0 you can leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. `($robotsFollow) ?: 'rel="nofollow"'`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you use `.` to [concatenate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) two strings, not `+` as you would in JavaScript. Also, as BluePsyduck mentioned, you don't have to escape all the characters as you're currently doing.

Change the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) statements as follows:

```
$returnText = preg_replace($urlPattern, 
    '<a href="$1" ' . 
    (($robotsFollow)? '' : 'rel="nofollow"') . 
    '>$1</a>', $returnText);

$returnText = preg_replace($hashPattern, 
    '<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23$1" ' . 
    (($robotsFollow)? '' : 'rel="nofollow"') . 
    '>#$1</a>', $returnText);

$returnText = preg_replace($mentionPattern, 
    '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" ' . 
    (($robotsFollow)? '' : 'rel="nofollow"') . 
    '>@$1</a>', $returnText);
```

Test:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo parseTwitterText('@foo lala');
echo parseTwitterText('#test');
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/foo" rel="nofollow">@foo</a> lala
<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23test" rel="nofollow">#test</a>
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/79676)